# apache beam (dataflow2) not using correct ProtoCoder when using protoc3.4

Tags: dataflow, protoc

I'm migrating to dataflow2 and also proto compiler3.4.

I'm not getting the Coder.NonDeterministicException on proto objects when I have nested protos with this a leaf:

```
message NodeId {
  optional int64 value = 1;
}
```

It is complaining that java objects aren't deterministically serializable.  But it shouldn't be using java serialization, it should be proto serialization.

When I add this, it works:
    pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(NodeId.class, ProtoCoder.of(NodeId.class));

`GeneratedMessage` isn't called GeneratedMessage with the new proto compiler.  Now it is called `GeneratedMessageV3`. And GeneratedMessageV3 does not extend GeneratedMessage.

So maybe the default coder registry needs to be upgraded to add proto coders for GeneratedMessageV3